# Tab host auto scroll using Horizontal scrollview– Programmatically

Tags: android, android-tabhost, horizontalscrollview

I am developing a sample application with `TabHost`, which is containing `HorizontalScrollView`. Here is my problem:

- I have more than 10 tabs, when i click on any of the tabs it should set the gravity as center? How i can over come this issue.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: hi gallery view is a best option to achieve this.

Comment: i know with galleryview but i want it with tabhost..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will involve some calculation.

Bsically you will need to scroll to the position to center a element.

```
int scrollX = (button.getLeft() - (screenWidth/2))+(button.getWidth()/2);
hScrollView.scrollTo(scrollX,0);
```

Where the

```
button -> It is the button you are trying to center.

screenWidth -> Width of the screen.
int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

hScrollView -> It is the horizontal scrollview.
```

But even with this method, you will not be able to center the end elements as scrollviews will not scroll beyond its bounds.

Comment: i want u to ask one more thing?

Comment: assume that i am having 10 tabs when as 1,2,3,4 when clicked on any of tabs it should be replaced at position 2..

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tablist.length; i++) {
        if (tabId.contentEquals(tablist[i])) {
            HorizontalScrollView scroll = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.horScrollView);
            scroll.smoothScrollTo(((int)(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.tab_width) * (i))), 0);
        } 
    }
```

I used: implements OnTabChangeListener.